# Creating a realm model

Tags: swift, realm

I am creating a model in Realm like this:

```
import Realm

class Contact:RLMObject {
    dynamic var nameLabel=""
    dynamic var image=""
    dynamic var isSelected=false
    dynamic var phone=""

}
```

But I don't want to use `isSelected` area in database. It is just a variable not important. Can I use this model as a database without `isSelected` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mark it as an [ignored property](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/ignoredProperties) and it won't be persisted:

```
import Realm

class Contact: RLMObject {
    dynamic var nameLabel = ""
    dynamic var image = ""
    dynamic var isSelected = false
    dynamic var phone = ""

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject]? {
        return ["isSelected"]
    }
}
```